# Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead

Tags: django

### Hola estoy utilizando un formulario de creacion de usuarios personalizados y intento agregar grupos al usuario que estoy creando pero obtengo este error y no he podido solucionarlo

**"Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead."**

models.py

```
class UsuarioManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self,username,email,nombres,apellidos,password,is_staff,is_superuser,**extra_fields):
        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            nombres = nombres,
            apellidos = apellidos,
            is_staff = is_staff,
            is_superuser = is_superuser,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user

    def create_user(self,username,email,nombres,apellidos,password = None,**extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username,email,nombres,apellidos,password,False,False,**extra_fields)
    
    def create_superuser(self,username,email,nombres,apellidos,password = None,**extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, nombres,apellidos, password, True, True, **extra_fields)

class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField('Nombre de usuario',unique = True, max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('Correo Electrónico', max_length=254,unique = True)
    nombres = models.CharField('Nombres', max_length=200, blank = True, null = True)
    apellidos = models.CharField('Apellidos', max_length=200,blank = True, null = True)
    imagen = models.ImageField('Imagen de Perfil', upload_to='perfil/', max_length=200,blank = True,null = True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    objects = UsuarioManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email','nombres','apellidos']

    class Meta:
        permissions = [('permiso_desde_codigo','Este es un permiso creado desde código'),
                        ('segundo_permiso_codigo','Segundo permiso creado desde codigo')]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.nombres},{self.apellidos}'
```

forms.py

```
class FormularioLogin(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormularioLogin, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Nombre de Usuario'
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Contraseña'
    
class FormularioUsuario(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Formulario de Registro de un Usuario en la base de datos

    Variables:

        - password1:    Contraseña
        - password2:    Verificación de la contraseña

    """
    password1 = forms.CharField(label = 'Contraseña',widget = forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Ingrese su contraseña...',
            'id': 'password1',
            'required':'required',
        }
    ))

    password2 = forms.CharField(label = 'Contraseña de Confirmación', widget = forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Ingrese nuevamente su contraseña...',
            'id': 'password2',
            'required': 'required',
        }
    ))

    # group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset= Group.objects.all(),required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Usuario
        fields = ('email','username','nombres','apellidos','groups','is_staff','is_active')
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(
                attrs = {
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Correo Electrónico',
                }
            ),
            'nombres': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese su nombre',
                }
            ),
            'apellidos': forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese sus apellidos',
                }                
            ),
            'username': forms.TextInput(
                attrs = {
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'Ingrese su nombre de usuario',
                }
            ),
            'groups': forms.SelectMultiple(
                attrs = {
                    'class': 'form-control select2',
                    'multiple': 'multiple'
                }
            ),
        }

    def clean_password2(self):
        """ Validación de Contraseña

        Metodo que valida que ambas contraseñas ingresadas sean igual, esto antes de ser encriptadas
        y guardadas en la base dedatos, Retornar la contraseña Válida.

        Excepciones:
        - ValidationError -- cuando las contraseñas no son iguales muestra un mensaje de error
        """
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Contraseñas no coinciden!')
        return password2

    def save(self,commit = True):
        user = super().save(commit = False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        user.groups.clear()
        for g in self.cleaned_data['groups']:
            user.groups.add(g)
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
class RegistrarUsuario(LoginYSuperStaffMixin, ValidarPermisosMixin, CreateView):
    model = Usuario
    form_class = FormularioUsuario
    template_name = 'usuarios/crear_usuario.html'
    permission_required = ('usuario.view_usuario', 'usuario.add_usuario',
                           'usuario.delete_usuario', 'usuario.change_usuario')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        nuevo_usuario = {}
        if request.is_ajax():
            form = self.form_class(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                nuevo_usuario = Usuario(
                    email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'),
                    username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
                    nombres=form.cleaned_data.get('nombres'),
                    apellidos=form.cleaned_data.get('apellidos'),
                    groups=form.cleaned_data.get('groups'),
                    is_staff=form.cleaned_data.get('is_staff'),
                    is_active=form.cleaned_data.get('is_active')
                )
                nuevo_usuario.set_password(form.cleaned_data.get('password1'))
                nuevo_usuario.save()
                mensaje = f'{self.model.__name__} registrado correctamente!'
                error = 'No hay error!'
                response = JsonResponse({'mensaje':mensaje,'error':error})
                response.status_code = 201
                return response
            else:
                mensaje = f'{self.model.__name__} no se ha podido registrar!'
                error = form.errors
                response = JsonResponse({'mensaje': mensaje, 'error': error})
                response.status_code = 400
                return response
        else:
            return redirect('usuarios:inicio_usuarios')
```

y basicamente me sale el error "Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.", eh buscado informacion al respecto e implementado varios metodos pero aun a si no logro arreglarlo si alguien pudiera ayudarme seria de gran ayuda..

gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en esta parte de tu código estas queriendo asignar directamente el valor de groups al intentar crear el usuario

```
if form.is_valid():
    nuevo_usuario = Usuario(
        email=form.cleaned_data.get('email'),
        username=form.cleaned_data.get('username'),
        nombres=form.cleaned_data.get('nombres'),
        apellidos=form.cleaned_data.get('apellidos'),
        # Aquí estas intentando asignar directamente el grupo
        groups=form.cleaned_data.get('groups'),
        is_staff=form.cleaned_data.get('is_staff'),
        is_active=form.cleaned_data.get('is_active')
    )
```

Lo que deberías hacer es borrar esa línea donde estás intentanto asignar el grupo en el create, y luego de crear el usuario (o sea luego de hacer el .save() ) agregarlo al grupo de esta manera

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group  # importa este modelo si aún no lo tienes importado

grupo = Group.objects.get(name='el_nombre_del_grupo') 
grupo.user_set.add(nuevo_usuario)
```

O como veo en tu caso estás trayendo los grupos de un select2 del formulario

```
# no estoy seguro que te devuelve aquí, 
# si es una lista de ids debes recorrer cada id, 
# o si es de objetos cada objeto...

groups = form.cleaned_data.get('groups')
# si es una lista de ids
for group in groups:
    grupo = Group.objects.get(pk=group)  # (pk=group.id) si son objetos
    grupo.user_set.add(nuevo_usuario)
```

Entonces así agregas el usuario a cada grupo seleccionado en el formulario.